# Symfony/Propel 1.4: Read from one, write to other DB

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

We have an existing project (SNS website+android/Iphone games) in Symfony 1.4/ Propel 1.4

We are experiencing extra load on DB server (say DB1). We are doing DB Optimization but as immediate solution we decided to create one more DB server in the way DB2 is exact replica of DB1 all the time. Currently we have only DB1, used for both read and write operations.

Now we need to move all read operations to DB2 and keep write operations (generally in transactions) on DB1 as it is now.

What are the possible ways to make those changes (On production server without much downtime) and if possible, with minimal code changes.

**Edit after first comment**

Based on link given by J0k and some other links, I'd done following on local dev environment.

1. Created a test symfony 1.4 project
2. Updated database.yml as follow

   ```
   all:
     propel:
       class: sfPropelDatabase
       param:
         classname: PropelPDO
         dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wzo;'
         username: root
         password: mysql
         encoding: utf8
         persistent: true
         pooling: true
       slaves:
         slave1:
           dsn:      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wzoslv;'
           username: root
           password: mysql
           encoding: utf8
   ```

   *Where database `wzoslv` is exact replica of database `wzo` except change in one test entry. On table `odd_play` row 26 (PK) column `result` entries are `WON1` and `WON` respectively.*
3. run symfony tasks

   ```
   php symfony propel:build-schema
   php symfony propel:build-model
   php symfony cc
   ```
4. Created a module and added following code:

   ```
   class wzoActions extends sfActions
   {
     public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
     {
       $con_write = Propel::getConnection(OddPlayPeer::DATABASE_NAME, Propel::CONNECTION_WRITE);
       $con_read = Propel::getConnection(OddPlayPeer::DATABASE_NAME, Propel::CONNECTION_READ);
       $oddPlay = OddPlayPeer::retrieveByPK(26,0,$con_write);
       echo "on write connection, result=".$oddPlay->getResult();
       $oddPlayRead = OddPlayPeer::retrieveByPK(26,0,$con_read);
       echo "<br/>on Read connection, result=".$oddPlayRead->getResult();
       exit;
       $this->setLayout('layout');
     }
   }
   ```

   Run `http://local.sftest.com/index.php/wzo/index` in the browser, output was,

   > on write connection, result=WON //Correct expected output
   >
   > on Read connection, result=WON //Not correct. That should be WON1

I guess passing `OddPlayPeer::DATABASE_NAME` while creating both read/write connection is the issue but that how it was suggested in online examples. Can someone please suggest where I'm making the mistake?

**Edit: Few more input**

I updated debug echos  in `lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfPropelPlugin\lib\vendor\propel\Propel.php` to check how it is returning the connection. Found that it is entering in following if (line 544-549)

```
$slaveconfigs = isset(self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves']) ? self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves'] : null;

if (empty($slaveconfigs)) {
  echo "inelseifif<br/>";// no slaves configured for this datasource
  self::$connectionMap[$name]['slave'] = false;
  return self::getConnection($name, Propel::CONNECTION_WRITE); // Recurse to get the WRITE connection
}
```

where `$slaveconfigs` are empty so returning write connection. Now the question is, why slaveconfigs is empty?

I also try editing sfDatabaseConfigHandler.class.php as defined in [old forums](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=22380) but doing so, break symfony somewhere and nothing gets display on web and even in logs.

Comment: Have you checked [the doc](http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/replication.html)?

Comment: Hi @j0k , I went through that URL but could not figure out how to use that info in symfony. I edited the question with code/configuration I'm trying based on examples available from different links. Can you please tell me where I'm doing the mistake?

Comment: Hi @j0k , nothing seems working for me. This forced me to play with core framework files to address emergency issue on production servers. I posted my solution. I know it is not a good practice but can you please look at it and wanted to suggest something.

Comment: This is crazy, official information from the doc doesn't work? Have you also tried on propel 1.6 (in local)? By the way, what you describe in your answer is a hacking solution I also found on the web but it was for an old propel version (1.2 I think).

Comment: Yes @j0k its (official info..) is highly improbable and I agree I must be doing some mistake but end result: it didn't worked for me. I later reverted back to propel 1.4 but that solution was tested on 1.6 first and worked on 1.6 too. I got idea from link mentioned in question but it was for Propel 1.2. On hacking, yes its truly hacking & I mentioned I do not recommend my solution in general condition but my condition was different. Production servers down and stackholder standing behind me for the solution, hacking is acceptable in those conditions, isn't it? Now looking for perfect solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure I'm doing some mistake but whatever suggested on official documents of Propel/symfony and even here at stackoverflow, seems not working for me. Probably official documents should take better care of programmers who do not have lot of symfony experience.

Although we do not prefer to edit core files of any framework/third party libraries but this force me to edit core files to make a working solution for me. The solution that worked for me is as follow:

**database.yml**
My database.yml file is as follow:

```
all:
  propel:
    class: sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      classname: PropelPDO
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wzo;'
      username: testuserwzo
      password: 
      encoding: utf8
      persistent: true
      pooling: true

  slave:
    class: sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      classname: PropelPDO
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wzoslv;'
      username: testuserwzoslv
      password: 
      encoding: utf8
      persistent: true
      pooling: true
```

After that, I edited Propel.php file as follow

**For Propel 1.4**
File: lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/Propel.php
Change line 542-543

```
// we've already ensured that the configuration exists, in previous if-statement
$slaveconfigs = isset(self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves']) ? self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves'] : null;
```

with (added one line inbetween)

```
// we've already ensured that the configuration exists, in previous if-statement
self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves'] = isset(self::$configuration['datasources']['slave']) ? self::$configuration['datasources']['slave'] : null;
$slaveconfigs = isset(self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves']) ? self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves'] : null;
```

Then in same file, changed line 560

```
$con = Propel::initConnection($conparams, $name);
```

to

```
$con = Propel::initConnection($conparams, 'slave'); //I know its bad practive to put hard-coded value but at that moment, I was more interested in working solution without caring about best practices.
```

**For propel 1.6 (We upgraded propel just to make this working but reverted back to propel 1.4 later as upgrade on production needs to be well tested.)**
File: plugins/sfPropelORMPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/runtime/lib/Propel.php
Changed line 601

```
$slaveconfigs = isset(self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves']) ? self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves'] : null;
```

to (Added one line before)

```
self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves'] = isset(self::$configuration['datasources']['slave']) ? self::$configuration['datasources']['slave'] : null;
$slaveconfigs = isset(self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves']) ? self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['slaves'] : null;
```

Then in same file, changed line 629

```
$con = Propel::initConnection($conparams, $name);
```

to

```
$con = Propel::initConnection($conparams, 'slave');
```

Then following test file was giving expected result

```
class kapsActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
      $con_write = Propel::getConnection(OddPlayPeer::DATABASE_NAME, Propel::CONNECTION_WRITE);
      $con_read = Propel::getConnection(OddPlayPeer::DATABASE_NAME, Propel::CONNECTION_READ);

      $oddPlay = OddPlayPeer::retrieveByPK(28,0,$con_write);
      echo "on write connection, result=".$oddPlay->getResult().$oddPlay->getPlayscore();

      $oddPlayRead = OddPlayPeer::retrieveByPK(27,0,$con_read);
      echo "<br/>on Read connection, result=".$oddPlayRead->getResult().$oddPlayRead->getPlayscore();
      exit;
      //$this->setLayout('layout');
  }
}
```

I still do not recommend editing core files but this solution worked for us as in emergency condition. Someone else, if needed, may use it in **emergency condition**. Still looking for perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a new level to `slaves` plus a `connection` entry, according [to the doc](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/blob/master/doc/database.md) (on github)

```
all:
  propel:
    class: sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      classname: PropelPDO
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wzo;'
      username: root
      password: mysql
      encoding: utf8
      persistent: true
      pooling: true

      slaves:
        connection:
          slave1:
            dsn:      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wzoslv;'
            username: root
            password: mysql
            encoding: utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers really work. If you find this 10 years later this might help.

There are a couple of reasons why:

1. It doesn't load the slaves part from the configuration. To include the slaves configuration. Add the following line to sfPropelDatabase.class.php:addConfig() line 133:

Before:

```
self::$config['propel']['datasources'][$this->getParameter('datasource')] = array(
  'adapter'       => $this->getParameter('phptype'),
  'connection'    => array(
    'dsn'         => $this->getParameter('dsn'),
    'user'        => $this->getParameter('username'),
    'password'    => $this->getParameter('password'),
    'classname'   => $this->getParameter('classname', 'PropelPDO'),
    'options'     => $this->getParameter('options', array()),
    'settings'    => array(
      'charset'   => array(
        'value'   => $this->getParameter('encoding', 'utf8')),
      'queries'   => $this->getParameter('queries', array()),
)));
```

After:

```
self::$config['propel']['datasources'][$this->getParameter('datasource')] = array(
  'adapter'       => $this->getParameter('phptype'),
  // New line below 
  'slaves'        => $this->getParameter('slaves'),
  'connection'    => array(
    'dsn'         => $this->getParameter('dsn'),
    'user'        => $this->getParameter('username'),
    'password'    => $this->getParameter('password'),
    'classname'   => $this->getParameter('classname', 'PropelPDO'),
    'options'     => $this->getParameter('options', array()),
    'settings'    => array(
      'charset'   => array(
        'value'   => $this->getParameter('encoding', 'utf8')),
      'queries'   => $this->getParameter('queries', array()),
)));
```

2. The configuration values don't match the docs. With the line above in place the following configuration will work. Note the username is set to user.

> 

```
default:
  propel:
    class: sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      classname:  DebugPDO
      dsn:        mysql:dbname=dbname;host=mysql
      username:   writeuser
      password:   pass
      persistent: true
      pooling:    true
      slaves:
        connection:
          slave1:
            dsn: mysql:dbname=dbname;host=mysql
            user: readuser
            password: pass
          slave2:
            dsn: mysql:dbname=dbname;host=mysql
            user: readuser
            password: pass
```

With that in place, it just works.